# Rails 5: Is there a way to run a single set of tests against the development database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I would like to run a single set of tests against the development database. My `seeds.rb` file populates the databse from a CSV and I want to ensure that the data is stored in the database in the way I expect. I don't want to run all tests against the development database, just a particular set.

I created an integration test. I thought I could switch environments in `#setup` but it looks like `Rails.env = 'development'` has no effect.

```
require 'test_helper'

class DbTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    Rails.env = 'development'
  end

  def test_total_settlements
    ...
```

Is it possible to run tests in different environments? If so, how is this done?

Comment: Why not seeds the test database and check how it's populated ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to create a class to seed the information into a configurable database, and then run tests against that class. In that way, you don't need to run the tests to an operational database and run that tests the number of times you want, without having to manually modify your development database in case the seed failed (like removing leftover records).

Once you have that class, you could add a task to your Rakefile and use your class :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest solution would be to just seed your test database. 
You can call `Rails.application.load_seed` before the tests you need seed data for.

Comment: The problem with this option is I'm seeding the db with a lot of data and it would slow down the tests considerably. It takes about 5 minutes to seed the database.

Comment: One possible solution for this is to create a separate seed file for your test environment so that you only bring in the sample data that you need for your tests. The seedbank gem makes this pretty painless.